# Sharepoint search is showing conflict results on when it search for sub-strings and when it does not

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search, crawling, managed-property

I am confused on how sharepoint 2013 enterprise search works, mainly when it comes to search for sub-strings. now i got this confusing scenario :-

I have the following item details:-

[image]

where is got a field named "`JiraNumber`", and its value = "`For seasons`".

now i did the following search inside my advance search web part , which produce the following search query :-

```
ANY(season)
```

and I got the above item inside the results, as follow:-

[image]

which mean sharepoint have match a substring "`season`" to "`seasons`".

so i tried the following search query:-

```
ANY(approve)
```

but i did not get any result... although the above item have its description as "approved" .. so why sharepoint did not match the substring "`approve`" to match "`approved`", as it did for "`season`" and "`seasons`"??

Comment: Is the Jira Number column indexed by any chance? On the list/library settings page, click on "Indexed Columns" under the Columns section.

Comment: @RayHogan i do not have any index on the list "_You have created 0 of maximum 20 indices on this list. These indices are: _"

Comment: If you do ANY(approved) do you get results?

Comment: @RayHogan yes i will get all the items which have their statues as "approved" .. bu if i do ANY(approve) will not get any thing

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the ANY operand as it was deprecated on SharePoin 2013. This means that it won't be supported in the future. Please check out the official documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394606.aspx#fql_any_operator).

Instead of ANY you can use OR, but in your case the query will simply work if you use JiraNumber:"for seasons" or JiraNumber:"season*". Note the * at the end. With this you are telling SharePoint that you want to find results that match the "season" prefix. That would work with Description as well. You would type Description:approve* and you should have the Project E being displayed. Finally, you can also type approve* and SharePoint will look in all fields not only Description.

-Hope this helps.

Comment: i am not sure if ANY is deprecated in SP2013, as the ANY will be used inside the built-in advance search web part, which is found inside the enterprise search center site collection template.. so i am not really using it explicitly or i chose to use it ,,but instead it is being used by the built-in advance search web part inside the built-in enterprise search site collection template, when you want to search for item that contain somthing